# Any way to get Tortoise Columns in Windows 7 or Vista

Tags: tortoisesvn, tortoisecvs

I know that Explorer in Vista and Windows 7 no longer supports extensible column views, but is there any way to get those columns in Windows 7 or Vista.  I don't mind using an alternate File Explorer, but not knowing things like what TAG or BRANCH I am on is becoming more and more annoying (having recently switched from XP to Windows 7).

Comment: I've been using Win7 for a while now and totally forgot about this, nor did I know that Win7 does not support this anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's going to be implemented in a foreseeable future. 
The idea of using a third-party file explorer is not bad but TortoiseSVN is a Windows shell extension and I don't think they'll take the path of writing plugins for alternative file browsers.

The subversion site lists [a number of clients](http://subversion.tigris.org/links.html#clients). Some of them are GUI tools and implement their own file browsers (for instance, RapidSVN). It can be an alternative and, of course, they don't need to fully replace TortoiseSVN.